# MVC httpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated always return false

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I downloaded NopCommerce open source e-commerce project.
It's ASP.NET MVC based and uses Forms Authentication.
When I login always it sends me to login page.
I debugged it and I found a problem httpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated always return false (httpContext  variable is type of HttpContextBase).
I checked forms authentication cookie, the cookie is successfully created also  httpContext.Request has found cookie. 
Someone recommended to add machine key to web config, I added but doesn't resolve.

I don't understand what's the problem ???

Comment: 'When I login (also not logged in)...' what does that mean?

Comment: I modified my question

Answer (score 2):

Check you got set the authentication mode in your webconfig

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```